# python - how to resize the data frame? pandas

Tags: python

I am a newbie python and would like to ask is it possible to resize the data frame like this below

```
Col1         Col2       Col3   Col4   Col5    
H01L31/06   None        None    None    None    
H01L27/14   None        None    None    None    
H01L27/14   H01L29/161  None    None    None    
H01L31/04   H01L21/363  None    None    None
```

into

```
    Col1
    H01L31/06
    H01L27/14
    H01L27/14
    H01L29/161  
    H01L31/04
    H01L21/363
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.concat method to combine all columns, then dropna

```
pd.concat([df[i] for i in df.columns]).dropna()
```